# Using media player and camera to realize live video chat in android,based sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, video-streaming, media-player

Yes,I have a requirement list as follows(maybe it can called simple ideas)

1.Using **Camera** and **MediaRecoder** to recording a video 
  (Now I can record and save it to a file)

refer: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

2.When recording video,I need send it to my Server for transit
  (I plan to use socket[TCP] to realize)

3.Server receive socket data and transit it to another client(android/PC)

4.At the same time,Server send video streaming to Android client by socket
(I try to using **ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(client)**,but it always catch IOException:setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000)

refer: [Stream live video from phone to phone using socket fd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116880/stream-live-video-from-phone-to-phone-using-socket-fd)

5.Android client receive Server's data and play it using **MediaPlay** and **SurfaceView**

6.In addition,I want server can switch video streaming from socket data or local file,when server transit data

This is my idea,but don't know if feasible and don't know how to achieve it
I wonder if you can give me some references or examples, thanks

---

btw, i am first time ask question in stackoverflow,before i always view questions in here,it helpful.if my question not clearly,please tell me,thank you.if i make some mistake,else i hope you tell me,thanks.

Comment: As it stands, the question is far too broad. Try asking a question about one *specific* aspect or problem you're encountering. Right now it reads as "How do I make Skype?"

Comment: Thanks.Ah,I think I just want realize a video live upload and play thought socket..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to read about sipdroid
have a look on https://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/
here you can find your answer
additional links.

1.http://blog.kylehasegawa.com/google-voice-voip-on-android-just-got-a-lot-easier-with-pbxes-peering

2.http://seethisnowreadthis.com/2009/07/11/get-sipdroid-to-work-with-any-sip-provider-on-your-android-phone/

3.http://blog.voipsupply.com/first-look-sipdroid-open-source-sip-client-for-android-mobile-phones

4.http://guardianproject.info/2010/05/26/how-to-setup-a-private-mobile-phone-system-for-android-and-beyond/

Comment: I had view some about sipdriod,but it not I want..Ah, thank a lot.