# Play Live Video Stream from one Mobile to another Mobile over network Socket in android

Tags: android, video

We are working on the Android App which required to Play Live Video Stream from one  moile to another ,Curently We are using the Parclable FILEDescripter Which is not giving the desired Result.So where I am Wrong Please Suggest.

```
Here is my Piece of code....

   mediaRecorder.setDataSource(ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket).getFileDescriptor());
mediaRecorder.prepare();
mediaRecorder.start();

The Error is :
 (I try to using ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(client),but it always catch IOException:setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116880/stream-live-video-from-phone-to-phone-using-socket-fd):

I found an open source project for implementing what I was trying. It processes the video with metadata through an IP camera. Although it does not send video directly to a phone, it does broadcast video for various devices to watch. The source code can be found at the following project page

http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/

Comment: Thanks for the quick Reply,But i have looked at this link before Insar.And this is not my Solution.Any ways thanks :)