# How to host a video locally in Android

Tags: android, video, localhost

I am working on a app that host a video(.mp4) from a primary
Android device.

Say in `http://192.168.43.88:8080/*.mp4` and the secondary device
connected using wifi will be able to stream the video (with a `MediaController` object and MediaPlayer)

I am have trouble finding any such example codes for selecting a video and hosting it from the Android device.

Here are some question I looked at

[Stream live video from phone to phone using socket fd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116880/stream-live-video-from-phone-to-phone-using-socket-fd?rq=1)

https://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

it may be easier to have a webhost on your phone on said port that opens up to a flash player that plays whatever video you've linked or is in a specific folder. an ip camera would only broadcast your camera. to play or stream a video, you need a video player. either the host (your phone) would need to have a video player on a web server.. or the client's browser (your computer) would need an mp4 player, else the file would just download from your phone to the computer. for the flash player, you could make it full screen and thus make it look nice.

Comment: the client side is working fine all i need to know is how to host the video from my device (need a reference code to work with)

Comment: what program are you using for the client side? the server side needs to be formatted to fit the specifications of the client-side app or viewer. you can't just plug any old videogame into a console. it has to be for that console. same with internet. you can't give a video streaming program a static video unless its designed for that and supports that. or are you asking how to host a generic webserver to host your video files on? if so, http://www.integratingstuff.com/2011/10/24/adding-a-webserver-to-an-android-app/