# Android: How to record video and send it live to a server

Tags: android, kotlin

What I am trying to achieve is recording video via my android device and sending it live to a server for real time video chat.

The server side isn't an issue, I have just not been able to find anyway to encode live video from the camera and output this data to the server via a socket (or any other way).

I have been banging my head against the wall for days and do not seem to be getting anywhere.
MediaRecorder has given me no hope, it crashes without any helpful errors most of the time and is unable to write to a ParcelFileDescriptor.fromDatagramSocket().

The closest I have gotten to what I am trying to achieve is only displaying the camera in a preview on screen. Eg.

```
val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
        val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
        val myPreviewView: PreviewView = findViewById(R.id.myPreviewView)
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(myPreviewView.surfaceProvider)

        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview)

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
```

Currently using API level 29 and it would be great if this can be done via camera2/camerax.

My experience is in backend using Python so please forgive any ignorance. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116880/stream-live-video-from-phone-to-phone-using-socket-fd

Comment: Tried MediaRecorder exactly as they have but it gives me "java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed".
This is the same error that I receive with anything involving MediaRecorder and video which is why I am trying to avoid it. 

Cheers

Comment: @abdiwan the example uses mediaRecorder with camera as video source, this is deprecated.